# How to derive the retarded Green's function matrix for a quadratic Hamiltonian?

Tags: fourier-transform, hamiltonian, greens-functions, second-quantization

Start with the quadratic Hamiltonian for fermion:
$$\hat{H}=\sum_{ij}H_{ij}\hat{c}_i^\dagger \hat{c}_j$$

and the definition of retarded Green's functon in time domain:
$$G_{i,j}^r(t_1,t_2)=-i\theta(t_1-t_2)\langle[\hat{c}_i(t_1),\hat{c}^\dagger_j(t_2)]_{+}\rangle=\langle\langle\hat{c}_i(t_1)|\hat{c}^\dagger_j(t_2)\rangle\rangle.$$

How does one derive the following matrix Green's function in energy domain?
$$G^r(E)=\dfrac{1}{E+i\eta-H}.$$
Here $H$ is the Hamiltonian matrix with element $H_{ij}$ in our Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$.

Comment: I have correctified the typo in the definition of Green's function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbf{Note :}$ Here equation of motion method is used to deduce the result OP is after.

With the OP's Hamiltonian:
$$\hat H = \sum_{i,j=1,1}^{N,N}\mathbb{H}_{ij}^{}\hat c_{i}^{\dagger} \hat c_{j}^{}$$
and the definition of OP's retarded Green's function as :
$$\mathbb{G}_{ij}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\Theta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})\langle \{ \hat c_{i}^{}(t_{1}^{}),\hat c_{j}^{\dagger} (t_{2}^{})\} \rangle$$
assumed here is the standard variant, presuming OP's question has a typo.

Here $$\hat O(t)= e_{}^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat H t} \hat O e_{}^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat H t}.$$

It can be shown that $\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$ (matrix of $\mathbb{G}_{ij}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$'s) satisfies the following differential equation's:

$$\left[i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{1}^{}}\mathbb{I} -\mathbb{H}\right]\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=\delta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})\mathbb{I}$$
and
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})\left[-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{2}^{}}\mathbb{I} -\mathbb{H}\right]=\delta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})\mathbb{I}$$
here $\mathbb{I}$ is an identity matrix of dimension, $N \times N$.

The solution of above two equations should clearly be of the form (the infamous jump discontinuity) :
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=\Theta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})+\Theta(t_{2}^{}-t_{1}^{})\mathbb{G}_{}^{<}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$$
with (the magnitude of jump discontinuity)
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{}^{},t_{}^{})-\mathbb{G}_{}^{<}(t_{}^{},t_{}^{}) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbb{I}$$
which can be deduced by integrating either first differential equation with respect to $t_1$ between $t_2+0^+$ and $t_2-0^+$ and using the above ansatz proposed followed by the identification $t_2=t$ or integrating second differential equation with respect to $t_2$ between $t_1+0^+$ and $t_1-0^+$ and using the above ansatz proposed followed by the identification $t_1=t$.

Further from the definition of $\mathbb{G}_{ij}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$ it can be seen that $\mathbb{G}_{}^{<}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=\mathbb{O}$.
Hence $\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{}^{},t_{}^{}) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbb{I}$.

Using thus deduced results and the resultant ansatz i.e.,
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=\Theta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$$
the following equations results,

$$\left[i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{1}^{}}\mathbb{I} -\mathbb{H}\right]\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=\mathbb{O}$$
and
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})\left[-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t_{2}^{}}\mathbb{I} -\mathbb{H}\right]=\mathbb{O}$$
which can be easily integrated from $t$ to $t_{1}^{}$ and $t$ to $t_{2}^{}$ respectively to get
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=e_{}^{-\frac{i}{h}\mathbb{H} (t_{1}^{}-t)}\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{}^{},t_{}^{})e_{}^{\frac{i}{h}\mathbb{H} (t_{2}^{}-t)}$$
which upon using $\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{}^{},t_{}^{}) = -\frac{i}{\hbar}\mathbb{I}$ gives:
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{>}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=-\frac{i}{\hbar}e_{}^{-\frac{i}{h}\mathbb{H} (t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})}$$
using which finally the following falls out :
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\Theta(t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})e_{}^{-\frac{i}{h}\mathbb{H} (t_{1}^{}-t_{2}^{})}.$$
clearly $\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t_{1}^{},t_{2}^{})$ is time translationally invariant, hence without loss off generality, the following can be considered instead:
$$\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t)=-\frac{i}{\hbar}\Theta(t)e_{}^{-\frac{i}{h}\mathbb{H}  t}.$$
Fourier transforming this as $\tilde{\mathbb{G}}_{}^{}(E)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dt\mathbb{G}_{}^{}(t)e_{}^{\frac{i}{\hbar}E t}$ finally reveals the sought after result :
$$\tilde{\mathbb{G}}_{}^{}(E)=\left[E\mathbb{I}-\mathbb{H}+i 0_{}^{+}\mathbb{I}\right]_{}^{-1}.$$