# How to derive the analytical expression for the retarded Green's function with quadratic Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hamiltonian, greens-functions

For two operators, $A(t)$ and $B(t)$ the retarded Green’s function is defined as
\begin{equation}
G^R(t,t') \equiv \langle \langle A(t)|B(t) \rangle \rangle^R
= -i\theta(t-t')\langle \{A(t),B(t')\} \rangle
\end{equation}

then one can show that
\begin{align*}
i\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t} G^R(t,t') & =
\delta(t-t')\langle \{A(t),B(t')\} \rangle 
- i \theta(t-t')\langle \{i\dfrac{\partial A(t)}{\partial t},B(t')\} \rangle  \\
& =  \delta(t-t')\langle \{A(t),B(t')\} \rangle 
- i \theta(t-t')\langle \{[A(t),H(t)],B(t')\} \rangle  \\
& = \delta(t-t')\langle \{A(t),B(t')\} \rangle 
+ \langle \langle [A(t),H(t)]|B(t') \rangle \rangle^R
\end{align*}
If the Hamiltonian $H$ in Schrodinger picture is independent of time,
then the correlation functions depend on $(t-t')$, not on $t$ and $t'$ separately. 
We can go to the Fourier space,the EOM becomes
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\omega \langle \langle A|B \rangle\rangle^R 
= \langle \{A,B\} \rangle + \langle \langle [A,H]|B \rangle\rangle^R}.
\end{equation}

**Starting with this formula**, I want to derive the analytical expression for retarded Green's function with the following Hamiltonian $H$ (fermionic system):
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_k x a_k^\dagger a_k + \sum_{m \neq n} y (a^\dagger_m a_n + a^\dagger_n a_m)
\end{equation}

This following is my solution:
\begin{equation}
\boxed{A=a_s,B=a^\dagger_t} \Rightarrow 
\omega \langle \langle a_s|a^\dagger_t \rangle \rangle^R 
= \langle \{a_s,a^\dagger_t\} \rangle 
+ \langle \langle [a_s,H]|a^\dagger_t \rangle \rangle^R
\end{equation}

\begin{align*}
[a_s,H] & =\left[a_s,\sum_k x a_k^\dagger a_k + \sum_{m \neq n} y (a^\dagger_m a_n + a^\dagger_n a_m) \right ]\\
& = \sum_k x \{a_s,a_k^\dagger\}a_k + \sum_{m \neq n} y \{a_s,a_m^\dagger\}a_n 
+\sum_{m \neq n} y \{a_s,a_n^\dagger\}a_m \\
& = x a_s+ \sum_{n} y a_n  \qquad (s=m \neq n)
\end{align*}

\begin{equation}
\omega G_{st}^R = \delta_{st} + x G_{st}^R + \sum_n y 
\langle \langle a_n|a^\dagger_t \rangle \rangle^R \Rightarrow 
G_{st}^R = \dfrac{\delta_{st}+y\sum_n G^R_{nt}}{\omega-x}
\end{equation}

But this result is the final solution? Or how can I further simplify my results?

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Quick hint:}$ Using [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450359) answer. You just have to identify a specific form of $\mathbb{H}=\left(x-y\right)\mathbb{I}_{N \times N}^{}+ y \mathbb{J}_{N \times N}^{}$, with $\mathbb{I}_{N \times N}^{}$ and $\mathbb{J}_{N \times N}^{}$ being identity matrix and [matrix of ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_of_ones) respectively. $\mathbb{G}_{}^{R}(E)=\left[E\mathbb{I}-\mathbb{H}+i 0_{}^{+}\mathbb{I}\right]_{}^{-1}$ can be found analytically using [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula).